# Algorithm to group a list based on category

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two lists like this:

```
list1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']
list2 = ['sunday', 'sunday', 'monday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'tuesday']
```

Now, I want to group items in `list1` as per the categories in `list2` and make a dictionary out of it so the output should look like this:-

```
grouped = {'sunday': ['item1', 'item2'],
           'monday': ['item3', 'item4'],
           'tuesday': ['item5', 'item6']}
```

what is the most fastest and efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is the second list always sorted? e.g. are the blocks consecutive? Or might there be repeats later on?

Comment: @MegaIng There can be repeats later on... Meaning it's not always sorted!

Comment: `{k: [i for _, i in v] for k, v in groupby(sorted(zip(list2, list1), key=itemgetter(0)), itemgetter(0))}` Imports: [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']
list2 = ['sunday', 'sunday', 'monday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'tuesday']

grouped = defaultdict(list)

for v, k in zip(list1, list2):
    grouped[k].append(v)

grouped = dict(grouped) # So it isn't a defaultdict anymore
```

This works even when `list2` is not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the efficient way that I could think of**

- Zip the contents of `list2` with `list1` and save it to a list `x`
- Iterate over the list `x` and Add/Update the contents of the `dict` d.

```
list1 = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6']
list2 = ['sunday', 'sunday', 'monday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'tuesday']

d = {}

x = zip(list2, list1)

for i in x:
    if i[0] not in d:
        d[i[0]] = [i[1]]
    else:
        d[i[0]].append(i[1])

print(d)
```

```
Output:

{'sunday': ['item1', 'item2'], 'monday': ['item3', 'item4'], 'tuesday': ['item5', 'item6']}
```